Some environmental variables only in VS Code Terminal
I'm on a Ubuntu 22.04 device with zsh installed as the default terminal.
I use QV2Ray as my V2Ray proxy. Whenever I connect to some of my V2Ray proxies some environmental variables are set in my terminal. 
The following is the result of printenv | grep -i "proxy" after connecting to some proxy using QV2Ray:
❯ printenv | grep -i "proxy"
all_proxy=socks://127.0.0.1:1089/
HTTP_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:8889/
ALL_PROXY=socks://127.0.0.1:1089/
NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.0/8,::1
http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8889/
no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.0/8,::1
HTTPS_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:8889/
ftp_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8889/
FTP_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:8889/
https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8889/

However even if my QV2Ray is not connected the same command shows that my VS Code terminal is connected to these proxies. The following is the result of printenv | grep -i "proxy"  even if my QV2Ray is not connected:
❯ printenv | grep -i "proxy"
HTTPS_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:8889/
no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.0/8,::1
all_proxy=socks://127.0.0.1:1089/
NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.0/8,::1
https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8889/
ALL_PROXY=socks://127.0.0.1:1089/
http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8889/
ftp_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8889/
FTP_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:8889/
HTTP_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:8889/

I could have tried and unset these variables for my current VS Code terminal, yet I use VS Code run configurations and for each run, it opens up a new terminal in which these proxies are set again and results in errors in running my apps.
For example, my latest Python code tries to connect to my proxy in order to call some outer API although my proxies are not up and running (since QV2Ray is off):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ashk/Job/python concurrency and parallelism/Asyncio/codes/s3/src.py", line 126, in <module>
    ex.run()
  File "/home/ashk/Job/python concurrency and parallelism/Asyncio/codes/s3/src.py", line 120, in run
    asyncio.run(self.main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/ashk/Job/python concurrency and parallelism/Asyncio/codes/s3/src.py", line 111, in main
    await self.progress(
  File "/home/ashk/Job/python concurrency and parallelism/Asyncio/codes/s3/src.py", line 73, in progress
    await crawl(url=url)
  File "/home/ashk/Job/python concurrency and parallelism/Asyncio/codes/s3/src.py", line 89, in crawl_performance
    client = httpx.AsyncClient()
  File "/home/ashk/.venv/asyncio-codes/lib/python3.8/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 1429, in __init__
    proxy_map = self._get_proxy_map(proxies or proxy, allow_env_proxies)
  File "/home/ashk/.venv/asyncio-codes/lib/python3.8/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 217, in _get_proxy_map
    return {
  File "/home/ashk/.venv/asyncio-codes/lib/python3.8/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 218, in <dictcomp>
    key: None if url is None else Proxy(url=url)
  File "/home/ashk/.venv/asyncio-codes/lib/python3.8/site-packages/httpx/_config.py", line 336, in __init__
    raise ValueError(f"Unknown scheme for proxy URL {url!r}")
ValueError: Unknown scheme for proxy URL URL('socks://127.0.0.1:1089/')

